# How to have an android start fresh with every restart

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

I have a large number of activities in my app that I transition between using intents.I would like the app to start every time as if it had been cleared from the background. I can't find anywhere how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like the app to start every time as if it had been cleared from the background."?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your app to start at the same main activity every time?

Comment: I mean that the app always starts from the same activity and can't be put in the background and then re entered in the middle of the app.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you want to start the app with the actvivities stack cleared.

```
Intent intent_activity=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            intent_activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent_activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent_activity);
```

use flags to make you shure the stack is cleared and declare the states of the life cycle of the activities

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,
LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```